# Влияет ли скорость интернета на результат запроса?

Tags: ajax, post, base64, upload

Есть скрипт, который отправляет на сервер изображение в формате base64.
Когда скрипт выполняется через "медленный интернет", то сервер выдает ошибку, а когда со скоротью все "ок" тогда без ошибок и у меня возник вопрос.
Не получается ли так что из-за скорости интернета base64 передается по частям и скрипт не может его декодировать в изображение и поэтому выдает ошибку?
Если это все таки так можно ли дать серверу команду чтобы он ничего не предпринимал пока `$_POST['imagetobase64']` не придет полностью, а потом начать декодирование. Сервер, естественно, написан на php.

Comment: При медленном интернете, какую ошибку получаете?

Comment: Что загрузка не удалась

Comment: В приложение PHP приходит полный набор данных. Первое что я бы проверил, не разрывает ли сервер соединение по timeout.

Comment: В `php.ini` стоит `max_execution_time - 600`

Comment: У вас php скорей всего работает за каким-нибудь web сервером. Не смотрели какой timeout у web сервера?

Comment: У веб сервера нету такой задержки т.к все локально, проблема на хостинге

Comment: На хостинге работает Ваш php скрипт, который принимает картинку, он находится за каким-нибудь http сервером, http так же имеет timeout. Если у вас локально все работает, то надо проверить, доходит ли запрос до php скрипта на хостинге. Если скрипт даже не начинает выполнятся, то это уже свидетельствует о проблеме со стороны хостинга, можно обратится в тех. поддержку хостинга. Вы сами генерируете ошибку "Что загрузка не удалась"? Знать бы конкретно что за ошибка